# Form Based authetication passing variable to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, web.xml

```
We are using a form based authentication and below is the snippet from web.xml 

 <login-config>
  <auth-method> FORM </auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp?fromIndex=true</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.jsp?fromIndex=true&ldapAuth=fail</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
 </login-config>
```

And i do have a loginfilter that processes the authentication. So if the authentication fails i also want to send a error code to jsp to display error message. Since the HttpRequest is not carried over to the JSP page when authentication fails i cannot send the variable by putting in http request .

is there a alternate way to pass a variable to the login-errore jsp page ?

Comment: So you want to pass a certain data from your Login filter to your application JSP, isn't it? But why do you say that "the HttpRequest is not carried over to the JSP"?

Comment: Yes, in the filter class i add a parameter into request. But What i think is when the authentication fails it would try to go to form error page, it would try to render that as new http request. Why i am saying this I am not able to get the parameter from the request in the error JSP

Comment: You can add attribute to session or request if authentication fails. And then read that attribute in your JSP page from HttpServletRequest or HttpSession JSP implicit objects.

Answer (score 0):

Instead through a parameter, you should put your data in the `HttpRequest` through **an attribute**:

```
// In the filter:
request.setAttribute("name", new MyObject());

// In the JSP:
MyObject obj=(MyObject)request.getAttribute("name");
```